# Load elements in array dynamically in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a custom slider where i'm trying to load element one by one as user clicks on next and previous buttons.

> Links:
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rwuxjd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Initially i'm loading only first value of an array in question array

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append("test",'test');
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/fetch', formData).subscribe(result  => {
    this.questions_lists = result;
    this.temp_questions_lists.push(this.questions_lists[0]);
```

`questions_lists` contains all the result from database but `temp_questions_lists` contains only first element of an array, Now on next and previous buttons i'm trying to clear array and load next value from `question_lists` array into `temp_questions_lists` array.

```
onNext() {
    if (this.counter != this.questions_lists.length - 1) {
      this.counter++;
      this.temp_questions_lists=[];
      this.temp_questions_lists=this.questions_lists[this.counter];
    }
  }



 onPrevious() {
    if (this.counter > 0) {
      this.counter--;
      this.temp_questions_lists=[];
      this.temp_questions_lists.push(this.questions_lists[this.counter]);
    }
  }
```

First time data is loaded in the slider but next time when i click on next button then i get this error :

> Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
> iterables are allowed

Any solution is highly appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **.push()** instead of assigning.

```
onNext() {
  if (this.counter != this.questions_lists.length - 1) {
  this.counter++;
  this.temp_questions_lists=[];
  this.temp_questions_lists.push(this.questions_lists[this.counter]);
  }
}
```

Comment: **this.questions_lists[this.counter]** this must be returning as an object instead of the array that's why you are getting error.

Comment: Thanks now it is added to array but how i will refresh it in my for loop  <ng-container *ngFor="let img of temp_questions_lists; let i = index"> this loop is returning blank data do i have to refresh any function?